# Python is inserting newline characters into requests header

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-requests, apache2

Some background. This code takes a data from a data collection script and then posts it to a secured REST API in Django. I have an api key generated and it is the only line in the file api.key. I also have the url to post to in the file post.url (it looks like http://example.com/api/ and then I concatenate the proper api node name on the end).

The code is below for my solar data api node (posts data collected from solar panels)

```
import gather_solar as gs
import requests
import json
import os

def post_solar():
print("DEBUG: start solar")
data = gs.gather_solar()
api_key = None
url = None
try:
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(here, 'api.key')
    file = open(filename, "r")
    api_key = file.readline()
    api_key.replace('\n', '')
except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR: " + str(e))

try:
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(here, 'post.url') #server will use different url
    file = open(filename, "r")
    url = file.readline()
    url.replace('\n', '')
except Exception as e:
    print("ERROR: " + str(e))

if api_key is not None and url is not None:
    authorization = "Token " + api_key
    authorization.replace('\n', '')
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        'Authorization': authorization
    }
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    url += "solar/"        
    url.replace('\n', '')
    print(url)
    req = requests.Request('POST', url, data=json_data, headers=headers)
    prepared = req.prepare()
    print("DEBUG: POST Headers: " + str(prepared.headers))
    print("DEBUG: POST Body: " + str(prepared.body))

    s = requests.Session()
    response = s.send(prepared)
    print("DEBUG: Response Code: " + str(response.status_code))
    print("DEBUG: Response Headers: " + str(response.headers))
    print("DEBUG: Response Data: " + str(response.json()))
else:
    print("DEBUG: Error with API key")

print("DEBUG: end solar")
```

I am running code on an ubuntu server via AWS and have Apache 2 setup and running. However, whenever I run this script, I get an error saying that my token is invalid and it shows the token as "Token abcd...abcd\n" . This is especially frustrating because I don't have this issue when I run the script locally (visual studio code on Win10) As you can see I have tried to remove any newlines wherever possible but it doesn't seem to be helping. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace()` does not change the string (strings are immutable); it returns a new string. So:

```
api_key = file.readline()
api_key.replace('\n', '')
```

leaves the `\n` on `api_key` and you are ignoring the new string returned by `replace()`.

You could just string the line before assignment:

```
api_key = file.readline().strip()
```

Comment: I had to set the key as a string using str(file.readline().strip()) but otherwise this worked. Thank you